# Реверс js массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь написать функцию на JS которая принимает заданный массив и реверсирует его. Я знаю о том что есть специальный метод для этого, но есть желание как у начинающего написать вручную.
Привожу код, который по не понятным мне причинам возвращает пустой массив.

```
function reverseArray(myArray) {
  var newMyArray = [];
  for (var i = myArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
    newMyArray.unshift(myArray.pop());
  }
  return newMyArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция работает, но неправильно (см. комментарий). Ну и в исходном массиве после нее ничего нет.

```js
function reverseInPlace(anArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length / 2; i++) {
    var temp = anArray[i];
    anArray[i] = anArray[myArray.length - 1 - i];
    anArray[anArray.length - 1 - i] = temp;
  }
}
    
function reverseArray(myArray) {
  var newMyArray = [];
  for (var i = myArray.length; i > 0; i--) { 
    newMyArray.unshift(myArray.pop()); // needs newMyArray.push instead
  }
  return newMyArray;
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];    
var newArray = reverseArray(myArray);
console.log(newArray);
console.log(myArray);

myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];    
reverseInPlace(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const revert = a => a.reduceRight((_, e) => (_.push(e), _), []);

console.info(revert([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: в IE11 не будет работать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, осёл умер, да здравствует `EDGE`. Ну или полифилл, для осла он везде нужен.

Comment: Не согласен. Много кто использует и разрабатывает под IE >=9 ...... так что все эти ES6 штучки - еще рановатая бесовщина....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нельзя затягивать прогресс из-за хилых ветвей развития (хотя они там, видимо, даже не думали стандарт читать). В любом случае есть `Babel`, он позаботится о них без ущерба для разработчика.

Answer (score 0):

## С изменением самого массива

```js
function reverse(a) {
  for (var l=0, r=a.length-1; l<r; ++l, --r) {
    var temp = a[l];
    a[l] = a[r];
    a[r] = temp;
  }
  
  return a;
}

console.log("" + reverse([]));
console.log("" + reverse([1]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

## С созданием нового массива

```js
function reverse(a) {
  var res = [];

  for (var q=a.length-1; ~q; --q) {
    res.push(a[q]);
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log("" + reverse([]));
console.log("" + reverse([1]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
console.log("" + reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```